# Setup project in C# without creating files in Windows Program Files

Tags: c#, installation, project, wrapper

I am about wrapping up a webapp written in PHP. Now for the deployment on the customer's machine, I want to write A C# wrapper that simply copies this project to a folder on local disk.

I don't want the C# Setup Project to create any files in Windows Program Files. I just want my webapp folder copied from the C# Setup. It would be great too, if the same C# Setup can install a third party web server. Any ideas?

Comment: why not use a [self-extractor](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables)?

Comment: What if they are deploying the PHP on *nix?